# How can I install the package python-uniconverter under ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.10, inkscape

I'm trying to do a plot with inkscape and if I copy the image with ctrl + c to another program, I get the error message that python-uniconverter is missing.

Further, I'm unable to install it with apt-get install python-uniconverter because it seems that the package is missing.

Do you know the procedure to install this missing package?

Thank you!

Comment: The package `python-uniconvertor` (note the different spelling) was dropped from both Debian and Ubuntu after 16.04. You can download the 16.04 package from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install using `sudo apt install /path/to/downloaded/file.deb`. It might work, it might not. Please remember to file a bug with Inkscape upstream -  they should not be recommending deprecated Python 2 software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download this package manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-uniconvertor and install with following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pillow/python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb \
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb \
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab_3.3.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb \
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-uniconvertor/python-uniconvertor_1.1.5-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb \
./python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb \
./python-reportlab_3.3.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb \
./python-uniconvertor_1.1.5-2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

## Installing on Ubuntu 20.04

To install `uniconvertor 1.1.5-4` you have to install additional the python-report-accel package.  These packages are also necessary to build inkscape 1.0 with

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/306203180/python-uniconvertor_1.1.5-4_amd64.deb  http://launchpadlibrarian.net/303745119/python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb  http://launchpadlibrarian.net/469960854/python3-reportlab_3.5.34-1ubuntu1_all.deb   http://launchpadlibrarian.net/469960848/python-reportlab-doc_3.5.34-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

and install with

```
sudo apt install ./python-uniconvertor_1.1.5-4_amd64.deb ./python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb ./python3-reportlab_3.5.34-1ubuntu1_all.deb ./python-reportlab-doc_3.5.34-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

The package python-reportlab-doc provides pdf/html docus.

Comment: Additionally, the packages python-reportlab_3.3.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb and python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb should be intalled (see the first answer) before uniconverter installation. python3* packages are not suitable.

Comment: Getting dependency error "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-uniconvertor : Depends: python-reportlab but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as the original poster. My system is Lubuntu 20.04.2.

I attempted abu_bau's solution, with the additions by v_mil. Inkscape still gives me the following error message when I try to Ctrl+C :

`UniConvertor failed:`

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/uniconvertor", line 13, in 
uniconv_run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/**init**.py", line 83, in uniconv_run
from app.io import load
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/**init**.py", line 69, in 
from conf.configurator import Configurator
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/conf/configurator.py", line 11, in 
from app.events import connector
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/**init**.py", line 69, in 
from conf.configurator import Configurator
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/conf/configurator.py", line 13, in 
from sk1libs.utils.fs import gethome
ImportError: No module named sk1libs.utils.fs

I have, however, found a cruddy workaround. I open Inkscape's XML editor, select the node I want to copy, and tell it to "duplicate node", which is an option selectable by a button at the top of the XML editor subwindow. That gets me a copy, pasted into the document. I can then move that around or do what I want with it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to install the newest inkscape version over snap. In Inkscape 1.1 copy paste works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the new version of Inkscape (v 1.2 as of July 2022), as it does not use deprecated Python library and therefore prints no error message while using ctrl+c.

Note that this new version is not available from Ubuntu repositories as of now (as far as know), and you would have to install it using [Inkscape's ppa](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/dl/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inkscape
```

I just tried installing it via Snap but it was not working at all, so I tried this way of installing (via ppa) and it works just fine.